# Installing datashader from bokeh channel

Tags: package, bokeh, conda

The question is simple: How do I install the datashader package?

The problem however might be a bit more complicated. I already tried several things and ended up with not finding the datashader package. I ran the following commands in my anaconda prompt:

```
[Anaconda2] C:\Users\Vuk>anaconda search -t conda datashade

Run 'anaconda show <USER/PACKAGE>' to get more details:
Packages:
 Name                      |  Version | Package Types   | Platforms
 ------------------------- |   ------ | --------------- | ---------------

 ahmadia/datashader        |    0.1.0 | conda           | linux-64, osx-64

 bokeh/datashader          |    0.1.0 | conda           | linux-64, osx-64
Found 2 packages

[Anaconda2] C:\Users\Vuk>anaconda show bokeh/datashader

Name:    datashader
Summary:
Access:  public
Package Types:  conda
Versions:
+ 0.1.0

To install this package with conda run:
     conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/bokeh datashader

[Anaconda2] C:\Users\Vuk>conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/bokeh datashader

Fetching package metadata: ........
Error: No packages found in current win-64 channels matching: datashader

Did you mean one of these?

datashape

You can search for this package on anaconda.org with

anaconda search -t conda datashader
```

As you can see, in first instance it says the package is there, but when I try to install it, it can't find it anymore.
Do you know what the problem could be?

Comment: This question is not programming based and should be asked in SuperUser site

Answer (score 3):

We're building Windows packages now, and will let you know when they are ready!  The existing packages are for other platforms.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: win-64 packages should be available now, so hopefully the original command will now succeed.